# Sending corrupt files by email python

Tags: python, excel, email, email-attachments

I'm sending an excel spreadsheet as an attachment using this code:

```
import smtplib
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.application import MIMEApplication
def send_email(subject, mail_body, attachment= None):
    to_addr = input("Enter the recipient's email address: ")
    from_addr = 'cloudops@noreply.company.com'
    content = mail_body
    msg = MIMEMultipart()
    msg['From'] = from_addr
    msg['To'] = to_addr
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    body = MIMEText(content, 'html')
    msg.attach(body)
    server = smtplib.SMTP('smtpout.us.cworld.company.com', 25)
    with open(attachment, 'r') as f:
        part = MIMEApplication(f.read(), Name=basename(attachment))
        part['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="{}"'.format(basename(attachment))
        msg.attach(part)
        try:
            server.send_message(msg, from_addr=from_addr, to_addrs=to_addr)
            print(f"Email was sent to: {to_addr}")
        except Exception as e:
            print(f"Exception: {e}")
            print("Email was not sent.")
```

And when I open the file I get a message that says:

> Excel cannot open teh file 'Cost Allocation - 201906.xlsx' because the
> file format or extension is not valid. Verify that the file has not
> been corrupted and that the file extension matches the format of the
> file.

[image]

Why am I getting this error and how do I correct this?

Comment: Have you tried looking in the contents of the received file to see what it looks like? That might give you some clues.

Comment: Excel will not open the file, because it says it's corrupt. But when I open the file using Sublime I see a bunch of numbers: `015c 7532 3032 304f 0930 14c3 1420 5248
ca22 5c75 3230 3236 a82c 52c8 ca22 5c75
3230 3236 b02c 5248 cb22 5c75 3230 3236
b82c fe7b 5ed2 c635 bec0 d0de d8c3 e9f9
f0b8 116d 460f dc5c 7532 3033 39de 5cf6
5c75 3031 3764 b4b1 ee1d 48d0 ecdc 25c8
166f 1eff 295c 7530 3264 63fc 0500 00ff
ff03 0050 4b03 0414 0006 0008 0000 0021
00b5 5530 23f4 0000 004c 0200 000b 0008
025f 7265 6c73 2f2e 7265 6c73 20a2 0402`

Comment: you have to open in `bytes` mode - `open(..., 'rb')`

Comment: Thanks! That worked.

Answer (score 1):

You have to open file in `bytes` mode

```
with open(..., 'rb') as f:
```

In `text` mode it converts byte used for `"new line"` and finally it sends incorrect data.